# Getting "iDeviceInstaller" error even when ideviceinstaller is installed on my mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, appium-ios

I am using mac OSX El Capitan. I have installed eclipse Neon in it. I have a full setup of running selenium scripts using appium on real ios device. For this i have "ideviceinstaller" also installed. I created a project in a workspace to launch an app on the device and it is working fine. But when i copied the same code to different project, it starts giving me the error

```
 org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not initialize ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on your system) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 33.97 seconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'MacBookBL9138C.local', ip: '10.104.150.28', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_73'.
```

I tried by uninstalling the current eclipse and installing eclipse lunar, but its still failing. I tried running same code in new workspace, but still same error.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the answer for this one. I missed to configure the path in eclipse.

For refer the below link for answer:
https://discuss.appium.io/t/error-could-not-initialize-ideviceinstaller-make-sure-it-is-installed-and-works-on-your-system/11699/5?u=tuhuynh